# Regular expression can't find zero after decimal point at tidyr::extract. Can you guess the reason why?

Tags: r, regex

```
'''
df <- data.frame(x = c(1.2, 3.4, 0.6, 7.0, 0.0))  
extract(df, x, c("integer", "fractional"), "(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)")  
extract(df, x, c("integer", "fractional"), "([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)")  
'''
```

The result is,

```
integer fractional  
       1          2  
       3          4  
       0          6  
    NA       NA  
    NA       NA
```

for both regular expressions.
Values like `7.0, 0.0` are not correctly split by `extract()`.

Why can't `\\d+` pick up the zero digits after the decimal point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem stems from the fact internally, the zero after the dot is converted to an empty char `""`. Here is a very efficient and fast solution with **data.table** and **stringr**, though a bit more verbose. I like verbosity if it goes along with speed and efficiency which comes from the parlance `set()`.

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame( x = c(1.2, 3.4, 0.6, 7.0, 0.0) )  
dt = as.data.table( str_split( df$x, pattern = "\\.", simplify = TRUE ) )
for(col in names(dt)) { 
  set(dt, i = which( dt[[ col ]] == "" ), j = col, value = "0")
}
setnames( dt, names(dt), c( "integer", "fractional" ) )
> dt
   integer fractional
1:       1          2
2:       3          4
3:       0          6
4:       7          0
5:       0          0
```

Please, note that `str_split()` does exactly what I said above. Look below:

```
> str_split( df$x, pattern = "\\.", simplify = TRUE )
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "2" 
[2,] "3"  "4" 
[3,] "0"  "6" 
[4,] "7"  ""  
[5,] "0"  ""
```

As you can see, the decimal zeroes are no more!

Answer (score 0):

Here, the regular expression was not an issue.
When I type in df, it shows
    x
 1.2
 3.4
 0.6
 7.0
 0.0
However, when extract look into df$x[5], it becomes 7.
In the same way, df$x[6] becomes 0.
Thus, extract fails for those two values.
To resolve this issue, you may use "0.0" instead of 0.0.

Comment: Actually you can improve the regular expression by making the decimal point optional. That is, `"(\\d+)(\\.\\d+)?"` this would retain the integer parts at least. It still leaves `NA`s for the decimal, because as @woodstck says, the 7.0 just gets read by R as 7, and the same with 0.0, to 0.

Comment: @JamesCurran Then the fractional column will have the decimal point and the fractional part such as ".2". But in your way, it would've been much easier to find the reason for NA. Thanks!

Comment: True. I did answer this at 3am. `"(\\d+)\\.?(\\d+)?"` might have been better.